# Looking for a way to re-run class static initializers

Tags: java, classloader, static-initialization

Is there a way to return a non-core Java class to a freshly loaded state?  I want the equivalent of unloading a class and reloading it from scratch.  I'm mostly concerned with static initializers and variables.

Problem context: I'm writing a robo-grader for student code.  One common student error I've seen is to use static variables inappropriately.  E.g., consider a Collection with a static count of elements it contains.  The collection will work fine the first time it is created and used, but fail on the next instantiation.  If I want my tests to be as modular as possible, I need a way to restore clean state after a test.

Right now I'm loading the Class more or less like this, and I've sketched how I want to use it.

```
    String classUnderTest = "package.class";
    Class unitUnderTest;
    try {
        unitUnderTest = Class.forName(classUnderTest);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Class \"" + classUnderTest + "\" was not found, can't continue.");
        printGradeAndExit();
    }
    // Run foundation tests (stuff on which later tests depend) using unitUnderTest.newInstance()
    runFoundationTests(unitUnderTest);
    // Now reset unitUnderTest for a static variable detection test
    lookForCommonStaticVariableMistakes(unitUnderTest);
```

Obviously, robo-graders can't be perfect, but I'd like to catch the common errors, and this is one of them.

According to the [Java Language Specification, Section 12.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7), supporting unloading of classes is optional (but would do exactly what I want).  Is there any way to do this without relying on non-standard features?

The last resort is to do an Ant build which runs a series of tests in separate programs, but I'd like to make this work in a single process if possible.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you posted that dictates using static initializers, much less 're-running' them.

Comment: When the unitUnderTest is loaded and newInstance() is called on it, the static initializers of the class will run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to unload the class for each run just use a new classloader. You can create a new instance of a `URLClassLoader` and load your students code using that (as opposed to putting your students code on the regular application classpath). Load the target class using that ClassLoader and then find a method of your choosing using the returned `Class` object and invoke it. If the method you wish to invoke is non-static you will have to first take a few extra steps to create an instance of the object via reflection.

Example using a typical `public static void main(String[])` method for entry.

```
String[] args = new String[0]; //Add arguments for main call.

//Add whatever classpath elements you need.
String[] classpath = {"file:///example/path/to/studentProjectJarFile.jar", 
                      "file:///example/path/to/studentProjectDir/"};

//Create classloader.
ClassLoader cl = 
            new URLClassLoader(classpath);

Class<?> mainClazz;
Method mainMethod;

//Find Class.
mainClazz = cl.loadClass("com.example.MyClass"); 
//Find the target method.
mainMethod = mainClazz.getMethod("main", String[].class); 
//Invoke method.
mainMethod.invoke(null, (Object) args);
```

In the this example `com.example.MyClass` should not be on the regular application classpath. If it is then that is the version that will get used instead of the one found by the custom classloader as standard classloaders use a parent-first delegation for loading classes.

Comment: I think I see where you're going.  It'll take me a bunch of careful API reading to figure it out, but I get the general idea.  I should be able to create new instances using new ClassLoaders (URL or otherwise), and each one is a separate static initialization.  That should suit my specific needs here.  Will that also lead to reloading of dependent classes, too?  E.g., static inner classes?  I don't need it now, but I could see needing it in the future.

Comment: @Mike I updated my answer to include an example as well. To answer your question: Yes, as long as the class wasn't loaded by a classloader that is a parent to your custom classloader such as the system classloader (application classpath), extension classloader (jre extension classes), or bootstrap classloader (jre classes).

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, I'd start a fresh JVM to assess each student's code.  There are too many opportunities for one student's code to interfere with another's if you try to do it all in one JVM instance.  Something as simple as an infinite loop ...

As a side-effect, this largely removes the need for custom classloaders, etcetera.

Comment: That's already the plan.  Each student gets a fresh JVM.  But firing up a fresh JVM for multiple, modular tests on a single student project?  That's a bit much.

Comment: I'd like to note that JVM startup is in the 100 ms range, which would be very slow for running hundreds of tests.

Comment: @Mike - "a bit much" - that depends on whether you value your time or the computer's time more highly.  Very slow is relative.  (FWIW, I've done this kind of thing for a class of 150+ students.  Admittedly I implemented the auto-marking as JUnit tests that the students didn't get to see beforehand ... and that approach has its own problems.)